# Parsing a textfile in java

Tags: java, text-parsing

I have a txt file that has ~900 questions that look like this:

On to the questions:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #0001 Which disease devastated livestock across the UK during 2001?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *Hand-and-foot
 *Foot-in-mouth
 *Hand-to-mouth
 *Foot-and-mouth

Answer: Foot-and-mouth

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #0002 Which of these kills its victims by constriction?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *Andalucia
 *Anaconda
 *Andypandy
 *Annerobinson

Answer: Anaconda
```

I have an object that stores the question, and objects that store the answer

IE:
Question.java

```
public class Question {
    private String questionText;
    private Answer a, b, c, d;

    public Question(String questionText, Answer a, Answer b, Answer c, Answer d) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }

    public Answer getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(Answer a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Answer getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Answer b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Answer getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Answer c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Answer getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(Answer d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return  questionText +
                "\nA) " + a +
                "\nB) " + b +
                "\nC) " + c +
                "\nD) " + d;
    }
}
```

Answers.Java

```
public class Answer {
    private String answerText;
    private boolean correct;

    //constructor to set correct answer
    public Answer(String answerText, boolean correct) {
        this.answerText = answerText;
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    public Answer(String answerText) {
        this.answerText = answerText;
        this.correct = false;
    }

    public String getAnswerText() {
        return answerText;
    }

    public void setAnswerText(String answerText) {
        this.answerText = answerText;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return correct;
    }

    public void setCorrect(boolean correct) {
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return answerText;
    }
}
```

I would like to make an array list that stores all the question objects parsed from the text file. I'm new to Java and programmed primarily in python before, and am a bit confused on how to do text file parsing in java as it seems a lot more complex. I know how to parse like line by line or a list of words for example. I don't know how to do it with the extra text in the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Sample of two line question:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #0016 Which word follows 'North' and 'South' to give the names of two
        continents?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *Africa
 *America
 *Asia
 *Australia

Answer: America
```

Comment: I suggest you to have a better question structure, you must make it pretty in the view, not in the model. Structure the txt like: `number;question;answers;correctanswer`

Comment: Imagine your file only contains a single question and its answers. Try to parse it and then expand your logic to apply it for several questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there here is something that might do the trick ;)

```
    String file = "text.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    int nbAnswer = 4;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {   
            if( line.contains("-----------"))
            {
                line = br.readLine();
                String question = line.split("#[0-9]{4} ")[1];
                while(!(line = br.readLine()).contains("-----------"))
                    question += " " + line.trim();

                String[] answers = new String[4];

                for( int i = 0; i < nbAnswer; i++)
                    answers[i] = br.readLine().substring(2);

                br.readLine();
                String sol = br.readLine().split("Answer: ")[1];
                System.out.println(question + "\nanswer: " + answers[0] + " " + answers[1] + " " + answers[2] + " " + answers[3] + "\nsol " + sol);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
```

`line.split("#[0-9]{4} ")[1];` is a regex that will allow you to split the string after a # followed by 4 numbers and a space.

At least it's a good beginning ;)

PS: There are many wrong thing about doing a beautiful .txt containing the questions etc.

1. It's harder to parse
2. It's bigger in size

You could for example change `*Foot-and-mouth` to `(*)Foot-and-mouth` to indicate that this is the answer instead of having 2 more lines for it ;)

Comment: The reason why the text file is like that, is the way I found it on the internet. I wouldn't make one like that normally.

Comment: Oki oki ;) anyways you can parse it like this or create a first program to change the format (it may be a good idea if the file is getting bigger)

Comment: If you're using Java 7, you can use the handy new [`Files.newBufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) method to skip most of the boilerplate code used to actually get the reader objects... I'd use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` as the second arg personally.

Comment: Hi thanks, the code you gave me is working pretty well, however for some questions they are on two lines (i'll edit the original question) and i get an array index out of bounds exception in those cases.

Comment: I edited the code ;) now it should work I leave the rest to you good luck ;) don't forget to validate the answer if it works ;)

Comment: Hey thanks! It works better now. When it reaches the end of the file, i get an array out of bounds exception. Anyway to deal with that?

Comment: Can you show me the end of your file because with your 3 examples I don't get any problems maybe you have a different end of file than the pattern shown

Answer (score 1):

Implement a simple [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) and parse it line by line. Read until you find a line that starts with `#dddd`, then read until you find a line that starts with `-`. Those lines make up a question. Read until you find a line that starts with a `*`, then read until you hit a blank line. Those are your choices. Next read until you find a line that starts with `Answer`, that's your answer. Repeat.

Comment: Seems better than a link-only answer now.

Comment: Based on that parsing scheme the file can be made much more compact actually. It depends on how relaxed the OP wants the file (if they want to be able to put comments in or something)

Answer (score 0):

If each your question takes exactly 10 lines in a file, it's much simply to parse it line-by-line, getting mean of each record from its position, not content:

```
public class Parse {
    public static final int OPTION_PREFIX_LENGTH = "*".length();
    public static final int ANSWER_PREFIX_LENGTH = "Answer: ".length();
    public static final String QUESTION_SEPARATOR = "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Marboni/tmp/test.txt"));

        try {
            while (br.ready()) {
                br.readLine();                                     // Skip separator (----).

                StringBuilder questionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String questionLine;
                while (!QUESTION_SEPARATOR.equals(questionLine = br.readLine())) {  // Reading lines and add them to question until separator.
                    questionBuilder.append(questionLine.trim()).append(' ');
                }
                String questionText = questionBuilder.toString().trim();
                String a = parseQuestion(br.readLine());           // Option a).
                String b = parseQuestion(br.readLine());           // Option b).
                String c = parseQuestion(br.readLine());           // Option c).
                String d = parseQuestion(br.readLine());           // Option d).
                br.readLine();                                     // Skip blank line.
                String answer = parseAnswer(br.readLine());        // Answer.

                if (br.ready()) {
                    br.readLine();                         // Skip blank line between questions, if exists.
                }

                Question question = new Question(questionText,
                        new Question.Answer(a, answer.equals(a)),
                        new Question.Answer(b, answer.equals(b)),
                        new Question.Answer(c, answer.equals(c)),
                        new Question.Answer(d, answer.equals(d))
                        );

                // Do something with it.
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    private static String parseQuestion(String record) {
        return record.trim().substring(OPTION_PREFIX_LENGTH);
    }

    private static String parseAnswer(String record) {
        return record.trim().substring(ANSWER_PREFIX_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks or your response. Unfortunately I forgot to include some questions that take up two lines in the file.